# How to download source code of a Google search results page

Tags: php, html

There is this php code that saves the source of page online to a local harddive. It works. Code one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- this program saves source code of a website to an external file -->

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://www.php.net';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($html)) {
    echo "<pre>cURL request failed:\n".curl_error($ch)."</pre>";
} else {
    //echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($html)."</pre>";
    $myfile = fopen("file.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $html);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If I replace the link to a search results of Google, namely https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car I get this code, code two:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- this program saves source code of a website to an external file -->

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($html)) {
    echo "<pre>cURL request failed:\n".curl_error($ch)."</pre>";
} else {
    //echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($html)."</pre>";
    $myfile = fopen("file.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $html);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But then Google **blocks it** and what I get on local harddrive is this:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dblue%2Bcar&amp;gl=CZ&amp;m=0&amp;pc=srp&amp;hl=cs&amp;src=1">here</A></BODY></HTML>
```

How can I modify the code two so that I get the source code of the actual Google result page? Thank you.

EDIT: modyfying the link to https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car is not a solution, I tried it..

Comment: `https://www.php.net` is not `https://www.google.com/search`, different security in place, your encountering a captcha because google doesn't allow scrapping of search results, whilst php.net doesn't give a hoot (probably happy someone is looking at the site)

Comment: _“EDIT: modyfying the link to https://consent.google.com/ml?continue=https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car is not a solution”_ - of course it isn’t, and it isn’t supposed to be. Google does not want you to just take their results from their UI, and do whatever you want with them. If you want to use Google search functionality within your site/app - then you should use the API they provide.

Comment: So there is no solution? Do I have to right click and save the source code of the search result page manually?

Comment: I think that much of the content delivered by Google requires Javascript anyway so cURL is not much use. You could signup to use their search api

Comment: `So there is no solution`... The solution is to use the proper API as already mentioned by CBroe.

Comment: Hello. I have found a way of solving the initial problem by fake user agent. There is a string that can be found here: http://useragentstring.com/index.php Here is the final solution: https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Mf03qwjNDFir7rnj4zP