# How to download source code of Google search result page having 100 results instead of only 10

Tags: php

I have solved the problem of downloading [a source code of a Google's search result page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441652/how-to-download-source-code-of-a-google-search-results-page). Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- this program saves source code of a website to an external file -->

<!-- the string there for the fake user agent can be found here: http://useragentstring.com/index.php -->

<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0');
$html = curl_exec($ch);

if(empty($html)) {
    echo "<pre>cURL request failed:\n".curl_error($ch)."</pre>";
} else {
    $myfile = fopen("file.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $html);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I wish to have 100 results instead of only 10. If I change Google search settings it has no influence on the code written above. The number of search results variable is stored somewhere and it is not a part of the query string while searching on Google...

Comment: Use the search API instead of trying to screen scrape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the &num parameter to specify the number of records returned (&num=xx)

So for your case, please change

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car');
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+car&num=100');
```